# Plot spectogram from mp3

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I am trying to plot a spectogram straight from an mp3 file in python 2.7.3 (using ubuntu).  I can do it from a wav file as follows.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scikits.audiolab import wavread
from pylab import *

signal, fs, enc = wavread('XC124158.wav')
specgram(signal)
show()
```

What's the cleanest way to do the same thing from an mp3 file instead of a wav?  I don't want to convert all the mp3 files to wav if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd install the Debian/Ubuntu package [libav-tools](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libav-tools) and call `avconv` to decode the mp3 to a temporary wav file:

---

Edit: Your other question was closed, so I'll expand my answer here a bit with a simple bandpass filtering example. In the file you linked it looks like most of the birdsong is concentrated in 4 kHz - 5.5 kHz.

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call
from tempfile import mktemp
from scikits.audiolab import wavread, play
from scipy.signal import remez, lfilter
from pylab import *

# convert mp3, read wav
mp3filename = 'XC124158.mp3'
wname = mktemp('.wav')
check_call(['avconv', '-i', mp3filename, wname])
sig, fs, enc = wavread(wname)
os.unlink(wname)

# bandpass filter
bands = array([0,3500,4000,5500,6000,fs/2.0]) / fs
desired = [0, 1, 0]
b = remez(513, bands, desired)
sig_filt = lfilter(b, 1, sig)
sig_filt /=  1.05 * max(abs(sig_filt)) # normalize

subplot(211)
specgram(sig, Fs=fs, NFFT=1024, noverlap=0)
axis('tight'); axis(ymax=8000)
title('Original')
subplot(212)
specgram(sig_filt, Fs=fs, NFFT=1024, noverlap=0)
axis('tight'); axis(ymax=8000)
title('Filtered')
show()

play(sig_filt, fs)
```

[image: Bird Song Spectrgrams]

Comment: Thanks. That works but it gives a slightly different spectogram. The original mp3 is at http://www.xeno-canto.org/download.php?XC=124158 . The main difference apart from the x-axis being labelled differently is that the version using the original mp3 and your code includes a blank period at the end and also at the top of the image. I made the wav version just by doing lame --decode XC124158.mp3 .

Comment: I just saw that you might know about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309155/extract-faint-bird-song-from-background-noise too. It would be great if you had any views on that too.

Comment: I simplified it to just use `mktemp` (it turns out avconv can't write a proper wav header in a pipe) and added more bins to the FFT, with no overlap. axis('tight') gets rid of the blank sections. You might want to also use `axis(ymax=8000)` since most of the power is below 8 kHz.

Comment: You're welcome. The filter isn't a perfect solution, but it delivers pretty decently for how simple it is, IMO. Typical audio isn't spectrally stationary, so normally it requires adaptive filtering.

Comment: @erykson Thanks. Now I have the small task of trying to find the bird sounds in amongst all the noise.  Do you have any idea where the buzzing/crackling noise comes from in the version that your python code plays?

Comment: That noise is in the pass band and gets amplified with the bird song. A simple bandpass filter can't block that.

Answer (score 13):

Another very simple way of plotting spectrogram of mp3 file.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from tempfile import mktemp

mp3_audio = AudioSegment.from_file('speech.mp3', format="mp3")  # read mp3
wname = mktemp('.wav')  # use temporary file
mp3_audio.export(wname, format="wav")  # convert to wav
FS, data = wavfile.read(wname)  # read wav file
plt.specgram(data, Fs=FS, NFFT=128, noverlap=0)  # plot
plt.show()
```

This uses the `pydub` library which is more convenient compared to calling external commands.
This way you can iterate over all your `.mp3` files without having to convert them to `.wav` prior to plotting.

[image]

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, most straightforward and can be done directly from python in a single script.

Comment: Great answer.
If you have a broadcasting-shapes error, your .wav is stereo. Use `data = data[:, 0]` to reduce it to mono.