# Doesn't python's ffmpy works with temporary files made using tempfile.TemporaryFile?

Tags: python-3.x, audio, ffmpeg, signal-processing, temporary-files

I am making a function whose purpose is to take a `mp3` file and **analyse and process** it. So, taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15313506/5341013) SO answer, I am making a temporary wav file, and then using python `ffmpy` library I am trying to convert `mp3`(actual given file) to wav file. But the catch is that I am giving the temporary wav file generated above as the output file to ffmpy to store the result to i.e. I am doing this:

```
import ffmpy
import tempfile
from scipy.io import wavfile

# audioFile variable is known here

tempWavFile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix="wav")
ff_obj = ffmpy.FFmpeg(
                      global_options="hide_banner",
                      inputs={audioFile:None},
                      outputs={tempWavFile: " -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44000"}
                     )

ff_obj.run()

[fs, frames] = wavfile.read(tempWavFile)
print(" fs is: ", fs)
print(" frames is: ", frames)
```

But on line `ff_obj.run()` this error occurs:

```
File "/home/tushar/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/ffmpy.py", line 95, in run
    stderr=stderr
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1490, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
TypeError: Can't convert '_io.TextIOWrapper' object to str implicitly
```

So, my question is:

- When I replaced `tempWavFile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix="wav")` with `tempWavFile = tempfile.mktemp('.wav')`, no error occurs, why so ?
- What does this error mean and what is the cause of it's occurrence and how can it be corrected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tempfile.TemporaryFile` returns a file-like object:

```
>>> tempWavFile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(suffix="wav")
>>> tempWavFile
<_io.BufferedRandom name=12>
```

On the other hand, `tempfile.mktemp` returns a string to a path to a real file which has just been created on the file system:

```
>>> tempWavFile = tempfile.mktemp('.wav')
>>> tempWavFile
'/var/folders/f1/9b4sf0gx0dx78qpkq57sz4bm0000gp/T/tmpf2117fap.wav'
```

After creating `tempWavFile`, you pass it to `ffmpy.FFmpeg`, which will aggregate input and output files and parameters in a single command, to be passed to `subprocess`. The command-line takes the form of a list, and probably looks something like the following: `["ffmpeg", "-i", "input.wav", "output.wav"]`.

Finally, `ffmpy` passes this list to `subprocess.Popen` and that's where it explodes when you use `tempfile.TemporaryFile`. This is normal because `subprocess` does not know anything about your arguments and expects all of them to be strings. When it sees the `_io.BufferedRandom` object returned by  `tempfile.TemporaryFile`, it doesn't know what to do.

So, to fix it, just use `tempfile.mkstemp`, which is safer anyway than `tempfile.TemporaryFile`.

From [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkstemp):

> `tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=None, prefix=None, dir=None, text=False)`
>   Creates a temporary file in the most secure manner possible.
>   ...
>   Unlike `TemporaryFile()`, the user of `mkstemp()` is responsible for deleting the temporary file when done with it.

---

You originally mentioned `mktemp`, which is deprecated since Python 2.3 (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mktemp)) and should be replaced by `mkstemp`.

Comment: thanks a lot, great explanation. But one doubt, did you say "just use `tempfile.mktemp`" but you provided the documentation of `mkstemp'

Comment: Sorry, forgot one "s" :) You should use "mkstemp" as "mktemp" is now deprecated (see my edited answer)

Comment: one more thing can't we somehow get the filename from the object returned by the temporary.TemporaryFile, because what it's returning is a file object ? and then ffmpy use that filename while calling subprocess ?

Comment: No, because actually temporary.TemporaryFile does not return a physical file. From the docs again :) "Under Unix, the directory entry for the file is either not created at all or is removed immediately after the file is created. Other platforms do not support this; your code should not rely on a temporary file created using this function having or not having a visible name in the file system."

Comment: Do you have a specific problem using mkstemp? Or you're just asking out of curiosity?

Comment: Thanks so much @filaton, well I am obviously solving some problem, but yes I am also very curious about as to why was this error happening ;)

Comment: You're welcome! Usually, breaking down your code and analyzing each line and/or looking at the traceback is enough. Don't hesitate to accept my answer if you found it useful :)

Comment: Well @filaton I looked at the traceback, but didn't knew that where exactly was subprocess exploding :)